# High difficulty - about LAMP stack and nosql

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, nosql

Let's say that I have few users, each user has a set of skills. I know that I can create json type column in mysql to hold all skills a user may have, the number of skills for just one user could be like 20, so there will be 20 records stored in the json. This json column will be involved a lot of search request. With few hundred users search user based on skills (the json column), how bad the performance would be with mysql? Also, the json column will be updated too, but maybe not as much as search.

So this is my idea to solve this problem, can I hold all the skills for each user in nosql with php?
like json {"user_id","skill A","skill B","skill C", "Skill D".................}

When I search users based on skill A, the query should first run from the nosql database, return data as JSON containing all user_ids, and then loop through the JSON array to get the list of users for skill A from mysql? Would this speed up the search performance a lot?

I don't really want to entirely switch from mysql to nosql since ACID should be still preserved.

If the mix of mysql and nomysql works, would you provide me some example?

Thanks

Comment: sql is designed to performance, create extra table for skills with index to user

Comment: really? each row as each skill for a user or each column as each skill? Either way, GRUD seems pretty slow..

Comment: I have had the pleasure of inheriting a system built on similar principles to what you suggest. It may work when it's small, but when it gets big you'll regret it. Just save yourself and any future developers the heart-ache and put the skills in a separate table

Comment: each row as each skill for a user table like `id, user_id, skill`

Comment: When you have 100000 user records and your boss asks you for a list of all users with Skill G. Do you propose to get all records then cycle them all in a loop, decode json and look for the relevant value?

Comment: lol..I will take your advice Darren..I haven't started yet..just want to know how's the performance with tons of search on skills with mysql

Comment: even if skill table will have more then 1*10^9 rows, result based on user_id you get in < 50ms for sure

Comment: <50ms sounds like a good number for search performance..not bad.......I will take your advice Marek..